# Mathematical definitions of in-degree and out-degree in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, notation, index-notation, network

**Introduction.**

- I have a **kNN graph**, which is a directed graph where each node $i$ has out-degree $k^{out}_i$.
- The out-degree $k^{out}_i$ is equal for every node $i$, and it is equal to the number of $k-$nearest neighbours of node $i$, i.e. $k^{out}_i=k$.
- This means that from each node $i$ of the graph, k-edges are starting at node $i$ and ending at $k$ nearest neighbours.
- Just to show an example, the following picture illustrates a kNN graph with $5$ nodes and $k=2$ (therefore $k^{out}_i=2$).
- Just for a sake of completeness, I write the in-degrees and out-degrees of that exemplifying graph: $k^{out}_1=k^{out}_2=k^{out}_3=k^{out}_4=2$ and $k^{in}_1= 4$, $k^{in}_2= 3$, $k^{in}_3= 3$, $k^{in}_4= 0$, $k^{in}_5= 0$.
- The set ${kNN}_i$ indicates the $k-$nearest neighborhood of node $i$, i.e. the $k$ nearest neighbours of node $i$. In the exemplifying graph we have, $kNN_1=\{2,3\}$, $kNN_2=\{1,3\}$, $kNN_3=\{1,2\}$, $kNN_4=\{1,3\}$, $kNN_5=\{1,2\}$.
  [image]

**Question.** I am not able to find a proper definition of in-degree and out-degree (except than by using the adjacency matrix - that I would like to avoid now). If I indicate two nodes with the indices $i$ and $j$, I would write $k^{out}_i$ as:

- $k^{out}_i = \left| \{ (i,j) : j \in {kNN}_i \} \right|$

(and probably it is not fully correct), but how to write $k^{in}_i$?

Maybe in this way?

- $k^{in}_i = \left| \{ (j,i) : i \in {kNN}_j \} \right|$

**Note.** $k^{out}_i$ in words: the out-degree of node $i$ is equal to the number (given by the two vertical bars $|\cdot|$) of $(i,j)$ edges, where $i$ is the starting node of the edge and $j$ is the end node of the edge, such that $j$ indicates the nearest neighbor nodes of the node $i$.

Comment: Yes, but since you are only counting how many elements there are, there is no reason to construct ordered pairs. So $k^{out}_i = \left| \{ j : j \in {kNN}_i \} \right|$ or just $k^{out}_i = \left| {kNN}_i \right|$, and $k^{in}_i = \left| \{ j : i \in {kNN}_j \} \right|$.

Comment: thanks a lot! ...just a silly doubt... do you think that showing $(,)$ and $(,)$ (i.e. ordered pairs) could help the reader to understand the direction of the edges? If not necessary, how can I help the reader to understand the direction of the edges?

Comment: I wouldn't use the pairs in these definitions. I'm a big believer of adding explanatory text instead of adding more mathematical notation. Definitions especially should be precise in notation and have sufficient textual explanation. If in-degree and out-degree are considered familiar concepts and you are just setting up the notation for them in this type of graph, then the explanatory text can be cut short.

Comment: thanks a lot. @JaapScherphuis! :-) :-)